# flex client side conversion of webpage to pdf?

Tags: apache-flex, url, pdf

i am trying to convert webpages to pdf on client side using flex. i need an api thing that takes the URLs dynamically and convert them to pdf, i considered purepdf and alivepdf both of them do not provide this kind of facility (as i look at them) is there any thing that can help

regards

Answer (score 0):

AlivePDF will create the PDF you wanted, but you're missing the part where you need to interpret the html from the website on your own and create the pdf.  You'll have to implement that part yourself...

Comment: Er, what?  [AlivePDF](http://alivepdf.bytearray.org/) - "100% client side PDF generation which makes you and your server happy ;)"